# sass: when do I need @include to call a mixin?

Tags: sass, include, mixins

According to the [doc](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6), we use `@include` to call a mixin, but in my use case, I have something like this:

```
@import "components/color";

/*NavBar*/

#g-navigation{background:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0), color(blue,base) 80%) !important}
```

For the mixin `color` (which is defined in `components/_color.scss`), I don't need to use `@include`, actually if I do

```
#g-navigation{background:linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0), @include color(blue,base) 80%) !important}
```

the mixin will not be executed and the compiler just keep `@include` as is in the output file. So why is this? And exactly when do I need `@include` for a mixin?

Answer (score 0):

For `background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1));`
you need direction and color values (names, RGB and so on) and you give mixin which is used to insert porperty + value not only value. You can use SASS variables for this.

Answer (score 0):

`@include` is for mixins; when you see something being used without it, like `color(...)`, that's actually a function. Mixins can return arbitrary content - multiple rule declarations, typically - but functions just return values. So you'll see functions used after the `:` in a declaration, and mixins used as standalone `@include` statements.